# can CDFDeploy command work via JLink

Tags: cdf-format, java

I tried the following command in notebook. It creates a .cdf file.

```
CDFDeploy["C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\myfile.cdf", 
 Manipulate[Plot[x^a, {x, 1, 100}], {a, 1, 10}]]
```

But when I tried the same in external java program, its giving $Failed.

```
import com.wolfram.jlink.KernelLink;
import com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkException;
import com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory;

public class testrun {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KernelLink ml = null;

    try {
        ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink("-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/10.2/MathKernel.exe'");
    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        System.out.println("Fatal error opening link: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Get rid of the initial InputNamePacket the kernel will send
        // when it is launched.
        ml.discardAnswer();

        System.out.println(ml.evaluateToOutputForm("CDFDeploy[\"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\myfile.cdf\",Manipulate[Plot[x^a,{x,1,100}],{a,1,10}]]",0));

    } catch (MathLinkException e) {
        System.out.println("MathLinkException occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        ml.close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping `CDFDeploy` with `UsingFrontEnd` does the trick